# How to make xdebug work with Zend Studio

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging, zend-studio

I have following configurations:

On remote machine:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so  
xdebug.profiler_enable=0  
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1  
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp/xdebug  
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1  
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

On Local Machine:

- I have zend studio installed with PHP Debugger set to XDebug .
- Accept remote session set to Any.
- I used remote connection(sftp) to work on the code.
- telnet localhost 9000 is working

I have installed easy XDebug firefox plugin.

Now when I try to run a remote script it is not giving any debug info.

I am using a get parameter something like this: `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=test11`

Please let me know if I am missing anything or tips on how I can debug what I am missing.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you also have the configuration parameter:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
```

See: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother use Xdebug with Zend Studio. XDebug does not receive any testing from the Zend Studio team. You might want to use Eclipse indigo with PDT which supports both the Zend debugger and XDebug. If you wonder why Zend can come to such a conclusion you might want to read:

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=24113&p=108183#p108183

Comment: They might not officially support it, but in Zend Studio 9 it actually works (Using XAMPP on Win7).

Comment: This is not accurate (anymore). In Zend Studio 10, it's super easy to setup XDebug and it's working like a charm. Better than Zend Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check step by step process for configuring XDebug with Zend Studio or Eclipse with screenshots on this page, http://vitalflux.com/configure-xdebug-debugger-for-zend-studio/

Comment: Please read [answer] and provide a summary of the link so that your answer keeps being useful if the link dies.